# Residuals and Homoscedascity in SEM with lavaan

Tags: residuals, heteroscedasticity, structural-equation-modeling, assumptions, lavaan

I intend on investigating longitudinal effects through a cross-lagged panel design, facilitating the lavaan package in R. Currently, I have set up a simple Model given the scheme and code below, in accordance to the lavaan tutorial, as well as various lecture notes by the package's author. I am using a robust method as my input data is not on all variables normally distributed - lavaan is suited to handle this, there should be no problem. There are no latent variables, as there is only one observed variable each, so it is an autoregression, really.

[image: Two Variables at three points in time / CLPM]

```
library(lavaan)

model <- '
  # linear part
    A2 ~ A1 # a12
    A3 ~ A2 # a23
    B2 ~ B1 # b12
    B3 ~ B2 # b23
  # cross-lagged part
    A2 ~ B1 # d12
    A3 ~ B2 # d23
    B2 ~ A1 # c12
    B3 ~ A2 # c23
  # variance
    A1 ~~ A1
    A2 ~~ A2
    A3 ~~ A3
    B1 ~~ B1
    B2 ~~ B2
    B3 ~~ B3
  # covariance
    A1 ~~ B1
    A2 ~~ B2
    A3 ~~ B3
'

fit <- sem(model, data = Data, estimator = "MLR")
summary(fit, fit.measures = T)
```

Now even without constraints (such as a = a12 = a23 and such) the CFI is above 0.95 and P-value > 0.01 (not great, but it's a start). I suppose this means the autoregression did work.
So for checking for homoscedascity, I would need the residual plot (residuals vs. fitted), given a predicted dependent variable from my model distribution in compairison to residuals of my acutal data. I don't really know how I would go about generating a model distribution like that given in my CLP-model, let alone the fact that it is bivariate. Or is homoscedasticity no longer a necessary assumption for this kind of model?

Could anyone please explain this to me and maybe even help me solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Robust methods in SEM are sandwich estimators, and the standard errors are robust to violation of the homoscedasticity assumption. (You can try this by generating simple data and replicating a t-test in regression

Here's some code:

```
library(lavaan)
set.seed(2020)
d <- data.frame(x = c(rep(0, 100), rep(1, 900)), 
                y1 = rnorm(1000))
d$y2 <- ifelse(d$x == 0, d$y1 / 10, d$y1)

with(d, t.test(y1 ~ x))
with(d, t.test(y1 ~ x, var.equal = TRUE))

with(d, t.test(y2 ~ x))
with(d, t.test(y2 ~ x, var.equal = TRUE))


fit1 <- "y1 ~ x"
summary(lavaan::sem(fit1, data = d, estimator = "ML"))
summary(lavaan::sem(fit1, data = d, , estimator = "MLR"))

fit2 <- "y2 ~ x"
summary(lavaan::sem(fit2, data = d, estimator = "ML"))
summary(lavaan::sem(fit2, data = d, , estimator = "MLR"))
```

Just looking at the p-values (I won't paste all the output).

First two t-tests, (where homogeneity of variance is not violated), and I do unequal (Welch's) t-test, which does not assume HoV, and equal variance, which does: 0.20 and 0.17 - pretty similar. Second two, where HoV is violated: 0.14, 0.60. Big difference.

First two p-values from lavaan, with ML and MLR: 0.14, 0.20 - pretty much the same. Second two, with HoV violated: 0.61, 0.14. Same as the t-test.